# Ubuntu-Gnome daily builds missing?

Tags: 17.10

Does anyone know what happened to the daily builds of Ubuntu-Gnome?  They are not present at http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-gnome/

Comment: It's written "The latest Long Term Support release is Ubuntu GNOME 16.04.3. <br> The **final** stable non-LTS release is Ubuntu GNOME 17.04." in their [homepage](https://ubuntugnome.org/). Probably they decided not to go on with a separate Ubuntu GNOME 17.10 and pulled out the the daily image. But I didn't find any official announcement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ubuntu GNOME was "merged" with "original Ubuntu" - Ubuntu GNOME is  obsolete now, because "original Ubuntu" starting with edition 17.10 will have the GNOME desktop environment as default.

Comment: If I download the daily build of ubuntu, and start it in a VM, I get the unity interface.  I believe that the switch to bnome as the desktop is slated for 18.04?

Comment: @CharlesGreen No, it just may look like the Unity DE because of the Ubuntu Dock, which was added by the Ubuntu desktop team developers. The daily builds of Ubuntu and the Beta of 17.10 contain the GNOME DE.